# Sending a custom header along with qtwebkit request

Tags: webkit, pyqt, pyqt4, qtwebkit

I'm doing some work with PyQt4 and QtWebKit, and in the web page request need to send a custom "Host" header along with the standard HTTP request. I'm not seeing any options for adding custom headers to the request, but this is all new to me so I hope I'm missing something. I'm looking here:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qwebsettings.html

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set headers on the [QNetworkRequest](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qnetworkrequest.html) that is sent:

```
QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl(QUrl("http://qt.nokia.com"));
request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "MyOwnBrowser 1.0");
```

To use that custom request when loading a page, use the overloaded [load](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qwebview.html#load-2) function:

```
myWebView->load(request);
```

Comment: Does this override all of the default headers, or does this just add and replace existing headers?

Comment: Any idea why it would hang when I use a "Host: mysite.com" but works fine when i use "Host: www.mysite.com"? I would expect the webserver to respond in either case, but in the first case the call just sits there indefinitely.

Comment: That behavior depends on the web server being used.  When a server supports multiple (virtual) hosts, it must use the `host` header to determine to which virtual host the request should be sent.

Comment: I am using web app that could allow specific User-Agent to allow and my [code](https://gist.github.com/tbhaxor/f4ffef16eb7bea33f910e55bd516a433) and user agent is not showing any effect ..

Answer (score 3):

If you want to apply this to **all** requests QtWebKit makes, you can subclass `QNetworkAccessManager` and reimplement its `createRequest()` function to modify headers accordingly.

Comment: Could you please tell how it is possible to be implemented if createRequest() accepts QNetworkRequest by const reference? As I can imagine setHeader() or setRawHeader() of the corresponding QNetworkRequest should be called.